# Why does my jQuery only toggle the first arrow in my HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of divs which are generated from some data. They each have an arrow that should toggle an expandable portion of the div. However, only my first div has the functionality to toggle the up and down arrow icon as well as expanding to reveal the content.

The template renders multiple times depending on the amount of instances in the back end data.

The rest of the divs show the arrow but clicking on it does nothing, I assume that means the jQuery is not running either. Is the syntax in my jQuery only allowing the first rendered div to have the functionality?

jQuery:

```
$('.remove-text').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.card').toggleClass('collapsed');

    if ($('.arrow-change').text() == 'expand_more') {
        $('.arrow-change').text('expand_less');
    } else {
        $('.arrow-change').text('expand_more');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<template name="printJob">
    <div class="row m-b-0">
        <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
            <div class="card hoverable collapsed">
                <div class="card-content card-content-width">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s3 m3 l1">
                        <div class="display-inline remove-text" href="#">
                            <i class="material-icons medium-3-rem arrow-change">expand_more</i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content dm-gray light">
                    <div class="col s1 m1 l1 more-horiz-col">
                        <i class="material-icons medium-3-rem more-horiz-job dis-inline">more_horiz</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4 m4 l4 view-edit-col">
                        <div class="label dis-inline view-edit">View/Edit</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                        <div class="dis-inline right delete-div">DELETE<i class="material-icons medium-3-rem  dis-inline">delete</i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try delegating the event handler to the `.remove-text` class using `$.on()` instead of `$.click()` like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove-text', function() { //your jquery });
```

You can read more about event delegation in jQuery here - https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

By binding to `$(".remove-text")` you are only binding to the first instance.

You need to bind to all of them with a for loop.

```
// Get all of the expand buttons
var expandbuttons = $(".remove-text");

// Loop over all of the expand buttons
for (var i=0, j=expandbuttons.length; i<j; i++){

    // Bind a click event to each one
    expandButtons[i].on("click", function(){
        $(this).closest('.card').toggleClass('collapsed');
        if ($('.arrow-change').text() == 'expand_more') {
            $('.arrow-change').text('expand_less');
        }
        else {
            $('.arrow-change').text('expand_more');
        }
    })
}
```

If you can provide a more complete example or a fiddle, I can post a more specific solution, but this is the general gist of what you need.

Comment: That's not true; of course this syntax binds to all matching elements - all _existing_ elements. But if the template here gets rendered client-side, likely the elements did not exist at that point already. And that's why event delegation is the proper answer here.

Comment: When I console.log the expandbuttons.length, I still get a length of 1. That remove-text class is repeated so not sure why the rest aren't being picked up.

Comment: It's been about three years since I've worked with jQuery, this was not the case then.

Comment: @RP12 As CBroe mentioned, make sure those elements are rendered BEFORE your jQuery runs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on` click listener to bind your class as told by Michael Coker. Also, use `find` to get the child element with class `.arrow-change` to change it's value.

e.g.

**HTML**

```
<div name="printJob">
<div class="row m-b-0">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
        <div class="card hoverable collapsed">
            <div class="card-content card-content-width">
                </div>
                <div class="col s3 m3 l1">
                    <div class="display-inline remove-text" href="#">
                        <i class="material-icons medium-3-rem arrow-change">expand_more</i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content dm-gray light">
                <div class="col s1 m1 l1 more-horiz-col">
                    <i class="material-icons medium-3-rem more-horiz-job dis-inline">more_horiz</i>
                </div>
                <div class="col s4 m4 l4 view-edit-col">
                    <div class="label dis-inline view-edit">View/Edit</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                    <div class="dis-inline right delete-div">DELETE<i class="material-icons medium-3-rem  dis-inline">delete</i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div name="printJob">
<div class="row m-b-0">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
        <div class="card hoverable collapsed">
            <div class="card-content card-content-width">
                </div>
                <div class="col s3 m3 l1">
                    <div class="display-inline remove-text" href="#">
                        <i class="material-icons medium-3-rem arrow-change">expand_more</i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content dm-gray light">
                <div class="col s1 m1 l1 more-horiz-col">
                    <i class="material-icons medium-3-rem more-horiz-job dis-inline">more_horiz</i>
                </div>
                <div class="col s4 m4 l4 view-edit-col">
                    <div class="label dis-inline view-edit">View/Edit</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                    <div class="dis-inline right delete-div">DELETE<i class="material-icons medium-3-rem  dis-inline">delete</i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.remove-text').on('click', function(){
            console.log("click");
    $(this).closest('.card').toggleClass('collapsed');
    if ($(this).find(".arrow-change").text() == 'expand_more') {
        $(this).find(".arrow-change").text('expand_less');
    }
    else {
        $(this).find(".arrow-change").text('expand_more');
    }

});
```

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gt45ptfc/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.card .content').hide();
$('.remove-text').on('click', function () {
    var itemSelector = '#item_' + $(this).attr('data-item');
    var isCollapsed  = $(itemSelector).hasClass('collapsed');     
    var label        = isCollapsed ? 'Show less' : 'Show more';
    
    $(itemSelector).toggleClass('collapsed');
    $(itemSelector + ' .arrow-change').text(label);
    if(isCollapsed) {
        $(itemSelector + ' .content').show();
    } else {
        $(itemSelector + ' .content').hide();
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="printJob">
    <div class="row m-b-0">
        <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
            <div class="card hoverable collapsed" id="item_1">
                <div class="card-content card-content-width">
                    <div class="col s3 m3 l1">
                        <div class="display-inline remove-text" data-item="1" href="#">
                            <i class="material-icons medium-3-rem arrow-change">expand_more 1</i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content dm-gray light">
                    <div class="col s1 m1 l1 more-horiz-col">
                        <i class="material-icons medium-3-rem more-horiz-job dis-inline">more_horiz</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4 m4 l4 view-edit-col">
                        <div class="label dis-inline view-edit">View/Edit</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                        <div class="dis-inline right delete-div">DELETE<i class="material-icons medium-3-rem  dis-inline">delete</i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card hoverable collapsed" id="item_2">
                <div class="card-content card-content-width">
                    <div class="col s3 m3 l1">
                        <div class="display-inline remove-text" data-item="2" href="#">
                            <i class="material-icons medium-3-rem arrow-change">expand_more 2</i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content dm-gray light">
                    <div class="col s1 m1 l1 more-horiz-col">
                        <i class="material-icons medium-3-rem more-horiz-job dis-inline">more_horiz</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4 m4 l4 view-edit-col">
                        <div class="label dis-inline view-edit">View/Edit</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                        <div class="dis-inline right delete-div">DELETE<i class="material-icons medium-3-rem  dis-inline">delete</i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```